# I am using angular smart-table and I want to pass a selected row to a declared table in a bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs

Here is the the smart table on the SPA, most other functionality is working fine. Selecting the row Will change the style but not watch is put on the row for further manipulation. I have also used a track by on a unique identifier, but, nothing seems to work on something that is logically very simple

```
<table st-table="smertAccountTabe" st-pipe="callServer" st-safe-src="Account" class="table table-bordered table-striped select-table" data-click-to-select=" true" 2px outset #ddd;>
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th colspan="3"><input st-search="" class="form-control" placeholder="Global Search" type="text" /></th>
      <th>
         <button type="button" style="width:140px; height:50px" class="btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
         Show Selected Records
         </button>                                     
      </th>
      <th>
         <button type="button" style="width:140px; height:50px; background-color:#337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;"
            class=" btn-sm" ng-click="isAllSelected">
         Selected All Records
         </button>
      </th>
      <th colspan="6">
         Display 
         <select  ng-model="viewby" ng-change="setItemsPerPage(viewby)">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>20</option>
            <option>30</option>
            <option>40</option>
            <option>50</option>
            <option>100</option>
            <option>500</option>
         </select>
         records at a time.
      </th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td style="background-color:#337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">Code</td>
      <td style="background-color:#337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">Account Name</td>
      <td style="background-color:#337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">Address</td>
      <td style="background-color:#337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">City</td>
      <td style="background-color: #337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">State</td>
      <td style="background-color:#337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">Zip</td>
      <td style="background-color: #337ab7!important; color: #fefefe!important;">SH</td>
      <td style="background-color: #337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">CO</td>
      <td style="background-color:#337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">BT</td>
      <td style="background-color: #337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">Created</td>
      <td style="background-color: #337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">Rates</td>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-cloak ng-click="isSelected = !isSelected;"  ng-class="{'rowIsSelected':isSelected}"
      ng-repeat="a in smertAccountTabe track by a.loc_code" ng-show="!acc.isloading">
      <td>{{a.loc_code}}</td>
      <td>{{a.name}}</td>
      <td>{{a.address1}}</td>
      <td>{{a.city}}</td>
      <td>{{a.state_code}}</td>
      <td>{{a.zip}}</td>
      <td>{{a.type_shipper}}</td>
      <td>{{a.type_consignee}}</td>
      <td>{{a.type_billto}}</td>
      <td>{{a.create_date}}</td>
      <td>{{a.rates_tickler}}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is the Bootstrap Modal. It iterates from the original smart-table but it will either show all the current records displayed based on how the user filtered the data or nothing

```
<!-- Modal -->
@*This is pop up widow when the "Show Selected Records" is fired*@
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog" draggable="">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content" style="width:1000px">
   <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h3 align="center" class="modal-title">Added Records for New Group</h3>
      <label>Name of New Group:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newGroupName">
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      <table st-table="selectedRecordsTabe" st-safe-src="Account" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th style="background-color:#337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">Code</th>
               <th style="background-color:#337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">Account Name</th>
               <th style="background-color:#337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">Address</th>
               <th style="background-color:#337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">City</th>
               <th style="background-color: #337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">State</th>
               <th style="background-color:#337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">Zip</th>
               <th style="background-color: #337ab7!important; color: #fefefe!important;">SH</th>
               <th style="background-color: #337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">CO</th>
               <th style="background-color:#337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">BT</th>
               <th style="background-color: #337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">Created</th>
               <th style="background-color: #337ab7 !important; color: #fefefe!important;">Rates</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr ng-if="rowIsSelected ==true " ng-cloak ng-repeat="b in smertAccountTabe">
               <td>{{b.loc_code}}</td>
               <td>{{b.name}}</td>
               <td>{{b.address1}}</td>
               <td>{{b.city}}</td>
               <td>{{b.state_code}}</td>
               <td>{{b.zip}}</td>
               <td>{{b.type_shipper}}</td>
               <td>{{b.type_consignee}}</td>
               <td>{{b.type_billto}}</td>
               <td>{{b.create_date}}</td>
               <td>{{b.rates_tickler}}</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
      <button align="left" type="button" style="width:140px; height:40px;" class="btn-success">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Create Group
      </button>
      <button type="button" style="width:120px; height:40px;" class="btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Her is the CSS for toggling the row if it is selected or not

```
table-striped>tbody>tr.rowIsSelected:nth-child(odd)>td,
.table-striped>tbody>tr.rowIsSelected:nth-child(even)>td
{
    background-color: #001A67 !important;
    color: #fefefe!important;
}
```

Comment: Got it, if anybody needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the ng-repeat for the original table on the index page obtaining data
from Ajax call

```
<tr ng-cloak st-select-row="a" st-select-mode="multiple" ng-click="selecRowAndEnable()"
ng-repeat=" a in smartAccountTable">
```

Here is the ng-repeat in the bootstrap modal that filters the selected rows. "Account" is the st-safe-src

```
<tr ng-repeat="a in Account" ng-if="a.isSelected">
```

This is the CSS class the for a striped table the change styling of 
the selected row.

```
.st-selected:nth-child(odd)>td,
.st-selected:nth-child(even)>td {
background-color: #001A67 !important;
color: #fefefe!important;
}
```